# Most performant / efficient way to action new and old items comparing two lists?

Tags: python, list, algorithm, collections

My use case is that I have a list of things (say original records) and a list of updated things (updated records). For any entirely new things in the updated list, I want to perform an action (say send a notification email). For any things in the original list, that are no longer in the updated list, I want to perform a different action (say log the old / outdated record). For any things in the original list, that are also still in the updated list, no action is required. Equality is determined by value.

Verbose:

```
for updated_record in updated_records:
   if updated_record not it original_records:
      send_notification_email_for(updated_record)

for original_record in original_records:
   if original_record not in updated_records:
      log_outdated(original_record)
```

I feel the production code I have is very readable:

```
removed_records = set(original_records).difference(updated_records)
new_records = set(updated_records).difference(original_records)
log_outdated(removed_records)
send_notification_email_for(new_records)
```

Note the *log_outdated* and *send_nofitication_email* functions will also need to again loop through the filtered removed_records and new_records collections.

Each list (original and updated) could potentially have many thousands of records however, so I'm interested if anyone has any suggestions for more efficient versions of the same logic?

Comment: Since you have working code, and you are asking about efficiency, this question seems more appropriate for [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use sets.

```
In [10]: originals = 'r1 r2 r3 r4'.split()

In [11]: originals
Out[11]: ['r1', 'r2', 'r3', 'r4']

In [12]: updated = 'r3 r4 r5 r6'.split()

In [13]: updated
Out[13]: ['r3', 'r4', 'r5', 'r6']

In [14]: for first_only in set(originals) - set(updated):
    ...:     print(first_only)
r1
r2

In [15]: for second_only in set(updated) - set(originals):
    ...:     print(second_only)
r5
r6

In [16]: for both in set(originals) & set(updated):
    ...:     print(both)
r4
r3

In [17]:
```